# Can mp4 files be pulled from the YouTube Data API?

Tags: oauth, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, mp4

Does anyone know whether I could perform HTTP requests from the YT Data API, asking for an actual mp4 file of a video that has been uploaded to a specicific channel that has granted me access to do so via OAuth2? I would need the mp4 file because I want to subtitle the videos I pull from those channels.

I read the docs, but I wasn't able to find any details on this matter, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't any [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos): download endpoint as there is the [Captions: download](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download) one. I would recommend you to use [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) to download your videos in an automatic manner.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The thing is though that my business needs to depend on such a solution. 

We want to subtitle videos of our clients without them having to externally (outside of their content production upload workflow) upload those files. Our plan was to integrate with their channel via the OAuth2 scope 'See, edit, and permanently delete your YouTube videos, ratings, comments and captions.' Then, every time they upload, they upload their vid in a private playlist. From there we'd want to pull that video and move on with the subtitling.

Comment: Do you know if there's any way of doing it so that we integrate into their content production workflow instead of them having to manually upload a video to our environment?

Comment: The only automatic approach I see in this precise situation is [*to pass credentials* of the YouTube account holding the private videos to yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-pass-cookies-to-yt-dlp).

Comment: Again, thanks a lot. Are you by any chance available for more consulting? Whether that is paid or not.

Comment: As it's written on [my StackOverflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7123660/benjamin-loison), you can reach me on Matrix or Discord. If I solved your problem, consider [accepting my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: are you sure this is the case ? I have seen quite a few companies pulling mp4 playlists from youtube and using those mp4 files inside their own players

Comment: @strix25 I described things as far as I know.